# "You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '%' operator." error in query statement

Tags: mysql, powershell

My Powershell script contains the query -

```psh
# This code defines the search string in the database table
$SQLQuery = "SELECT bug_id, 
       bug_status, 
       resolution, 
       short_desc, 
       DATE_FORMAT(deadline, "%m/%d/%Y")
FROM   bugs 
WHERE  ( bug_status IN ( 'RESOLVED', 'VERIFIED', 'INTEST' ) 
         AND deadline BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
       ) 
        OR ( bug_status IN ( 'RESOLVED', 'VERIFIED', 'INTEST' ) 
             AND deadline BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND 
                                  CURDATE() )        
       ORDER BY deadline ASC

"
```

On running the script, it fails at the date formatting part with below error -

```
You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '%' operator.
At line:5 char:32
+        DATE_FORMAT(deadline, "% <<<< m/%d/%Y")
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression
```

Any suggestions on how to escape these characters but at the same time, it should impact the actual query that is going to be fired on MySql database?

Answer (score 0):

You're using double quotes inside a double-quoted string. The unescaped nested double quotes prematurely terminate the string, so PowerShell interprets `%` as an operator, not as part of the string.

Try replacing the nested double quotes with single quotes, and make your string a proper multiline string:

```psh
$SQLQuery = @"
SELECT bug_id, 
       ...
       DATE_FORMAT(deadline, '%m/%d/%Y')
       ...
"@
```

Comment: The first approach worked but it impacted my query thus omitting results for deadline column altogether.

Second approach does not help since I have other where clauses wrapped in single quotes. `bug_status IN ( 'RESOLVED', 'VERIFIED', 'INTEST' )`

Comment: Yes, the query works fine when executed in MySql client.

Comment: Try replacing the nested double quotes with single quotes.

Comment: Following error faced on replacing nested double quotes with single quotes. `Unexpected token 'RESOLVED', 'VERIFIED', 'INTEST' )
         AND deadline BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
       )`

Comment: Try with a multiline string. Also, is that a PowerShell error or a MySQL error?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Try with a multiline string" That error is being faced in powershell terminal.